# Magento2 when site is loading than facing issue

Tags: magento2, cache, redis, cm-redissession

I have facing issue in magento2 when site is loading.

> Fatal error: Uncaught CredisException: Connection to Redis
>   127.0.0.1:6379 failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (1) Connection refused in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php:475 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(471):
>   Credis_Client->connect() #1
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(784):
>   Credis_Client->connect() #2
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(637):
>   Credis_Client->__call('select', Array) #3
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(393):
>   Credis_Client->select(1) #4
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(250):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->_applyClientOptions(Object(Credis_Client)) #5
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array) #6
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Arra in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php on line 475

Comment: So you have a problem with Redis.  What is the Redis error log?

Comment: See the status of redis cache and check if correct credentials are pointed to it

Comment: Please check your redis credential is corrected.

Comment: yes, Credential is corrected.

Comment: You still have not let us know about any errors.  Is the basic install working ok? Ping Pong etc? https://redis.io/topics/quickstart

Comment: your redis is not available at `127.0.0.1:6379`